# Demonstration of Composition for Swing

Tags: java, swing, composition

I'm currently undertaking a Java programming course in pursuit of a degree, and while I have a bit of familiarity with basic programming concepts already, I've never used Java specifically prior to this course. In the interest of trying to be a better programmer, I've researched the topics covered by each assignment and chapter independently, and several times I've identified practices in the book that seem to be against accepted standards (use of double for currency, etc.) and ended up learning more from third-party information in order to try to write better code.

The current chapter covers an introduction to Swing and the creation of GUIs, but it very explicitly recommends using inheritance to extend Swing classes with absolutely no mention of using composition at all, something the most basic search (on StackOverflow and elsewhere) seems to suggest would be a more effective solution. As such, none of the examples in the chapter cover using composition to create and implement Swing GUIs.

Can anyone direct me towards any suggested online resources that provide properly written beginner-level examples/demonstrations of Swing GUIs implemented using composition?

Comment: Even if you subclass Swing classes, you can't use Swing without composition. A typical GUI is created by adding components to panels, panels to frames, etc. That's composition.

Comment: see composition vs inheritance [here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html?page=2) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), compisition is about return,  inheritance about extend, to try avoiding Whatever extend Xxx inplements Xxx

Comment: To clarify, the book specifically suggests extending Swing classes in creating a GUI object rather than creating a new object that contains one, and as such the demonstrations and examples provided are all "Is-A" rather than "Has-A." I am seeking well-written simple examples of a Swing GUI implemented using a "Has-A" relationship.

Comment: So, how does the book add a button to a panel, for example? I don't see how it could do that without using composition.

Answer (score 1):

only comment, not an answer, question to OP and knowledge based on her/his book

simplest example is to create JFrame with JPanel and JButton

---

Composition

create one class with local variables for every JComponents

or

three classes with return JFrame, JPanel, JButton

---

Inheritance

three classes with

class one extend JFrame

class two extend JPanel

class three extend JButton

or

another Zoo

---

now is question how to change BackGround for Object created for both of ways, Composition and Inheritance

Comment: Suppose the book creates a GUI object using "public class WindowType extends JFrame", defines components (panels, labels, etc.), sets information in the constructor (setTitle(), setSize()), and has methods to build a panel using those components. Now suppose I wanted to create the same window by "public class WindowType" and creating a new private JFrame object inside of this class rather than extending the JFrame class. What I'm ultimately getting at (and was looking for examples of) is whether there would be any significant changes to the structure of the resulting class due to this change.

Comment: yes but JFrame isn't accesible, sure there is this.setXxx, but for very simple GUI, otherwise this can be missinterpreted, create an local variable for JFrame too